# Network interfaces cannot be found

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp

I made a virtual machine of my hosted ubuntu server 12.04 but the network is not working on it

the `/etc/init/interfaces/` only showed the loopback interface, I added eth0 as static and dhcp then restart the virtual machine but it did not work

running the command `ifconfig -a` does show eth2 and lo, I modified the interfaces file and replaced `eth0` with `eth2`, after a restart it is still not working

running the command `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` shows that eth0, eth1, eth2 and eth0:1 cannot be found

running `sudo service networking restart` gives `unknown instance: networking stop/waiting`

Comment: a colleague is suggesting that the network adapter driver is setup for the remote server where I got the image from but not setup to work as a virtual machine, while it does sound as the cause of my problem I am not sure how to fix it

Comment: **Voted to reopen as this is a Q&A by the same user.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running these two commands sorted out the issue

```
sudo dpkg -i network-manager_*.deb
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: "dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'network-manager_*.deb': No such file or directory"

Comment: @Mathy, same for me. Did you resolve it somehow ?

Comment: @Ilya.K. Sadly not, I set up a completely new VM...